# Data retrieval from SQL SERVER using jsp code

Tags: sql-server, jsp, servlets

```
    <tr>
              <th> ID number</th>
              <th>spare part id</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th> model</th>
              <th>Price</th>
               <th> Expire Date</th>
              <th> Manufacture Date</th>
              <th>state</th>
      </tr>

      <% while (rs.next()){ %>

      <tr>
      <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getInt(0)); %></td>
      <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getString(1)); %></td>
      <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getString(3)); %></td>
      <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getString(4)); %></td>
      <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getFloat(5)); %></td>
      <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getString(5)); %></td>
      <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getString(5)); %></td>
     <td class="container"> <%out.print(rs.getString(5)); %></td>
      </tr>
```

This is my code to display the out put in table form but the stack trace says

> "javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 0 is out of
>   range."

is there anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made an error in placing closing brace. i got my error